# Are Software Usage Questions Acceptable?

Tags: support

I'm having a problem with gimp, and I am not sure if this is the right place to ask the question.

*If this is not within the scope of the community can anybody recommend any other communities where I can ask the question*

Comment: Also if you can phrase the question universally so you are solving a problem. Not just with this tool but in general i t might be that the real answer lies outside of gimp (such as using ImageMagick for example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are -- **but**. Please don't ask a question 'how do I do this in GIMP' and leave it at that. We kindly ask that you put some effort in your question by explaining what you want to achieve (if possible with screenshots) and what you have tried in vain (definitely with screenshots).

The one exception is when your question is a 'tech support' issue. That would be when you have a malfunction or other technical problem in your version of the software. We are poorly equipped to handle errors or bugs. Please ask those questions at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or, preferably, at the GIMP site or forums.

If your question does obey these rules, it is right at home here.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask tool questions. But it would be better for you if you did not. Lets take your first question on [main GD](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58359/how-do-i-use-the-cage-tool-in-gimp) as an example.

The way you are asking is in many ways unconductive:

- You are only minimally describing your goal. Thus

  - It's hard to suggest an alternative workflow as you have scoped yourself in a corner.
  - You're reducing the list of people that can answer your question.
- You are not describing why.

  - The entire situation might be circumvented.
  - It makes the question more interesting.

You are far from the worst offender. But as you can begin to understand, there may be a better way to ask your question.

Let's take an example:

- [How can I make a shape look like it is made of glass?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51538/how-can-i-make-a-shape-look-like-it-is-made-of-glass)

Note how simple the question is. It does not need to specify a tool. It describes a problem. This allows the answer to use stylisation to overcome the problem. It's not restrictive, but sets a goal. Note: at the same time it is also a more demanding question to answer.